# Сортировка каждой строки в dataframe по возрастанию python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

pd.DataFrame:

```
101 99 110
40 10 55
200 42 81
```

как отсортировать строки по возрастанию так, чтобы:

```
99 101 110
10 40 55
42 81 200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логика примерно та же, что и *@strawdog*

```
a = [[101, 99, 110],
[40, 10, 55],
[200, 42, 81]]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df = df.apply(lambda x: np.sort(x), raw=True, axis=1)
print(df)

>>>    
    0    1    2
0  99  101  110
1  10   40   55
2  42   81  200
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо

Comment: @Anna, решение от strawdog на больших данных будет гораздо быстрее работать)

Answer (score 4):

Воспользуйтесь функционалом numpy:

```
#import numpy as np

df.values.sort(axis=1)
```

теперь df:

```
    a    b    c
0  99  101  110
1  10   40   55
2  42   81  200
```